# Is there an ID that will uniquely group all the logs - APM Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, nest, querydsl, apm

When I run the command show below, I get the logs of the per each transaction made on a single activity (from start to end).

```
GET /apm-*-transaction/_search
{
  "size": 100,
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "@timestamp": {
        "gte": "2021-07-19T12:58:40.710-05:00",
        "lt": "2021-07-19T13:08:40.710-05:00"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is a sample (2 out of 5 results) shown below:

```
{
  "took" : 2,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 2,
    "successful" : 2,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 5,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "apm-7.13.0-transaction-000002",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "3CXzv3oB2DAWJifJt8jM",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "agent" : {
            "name" : "dotnet",
            "version" : "1.11.0+a4eb5008af64ca52fe6973c18810c0c8c7a99554"
          },
          "source" : {
            "ip" : "::1"
          },
          "processor" : {
            "name" : "transaction",
            "event" : "transaction"
          },
          "url" : {
            "path" : "/",
            "original" : "https://localhost:5001/",
            "scheme" : "HTTP",
            "domain" : "localhost",
            "full" : "https://localhost:5001/"
          },
          "observer" : {
            "hostname" : "ef75b7ae7c69",
            "id" : "de63825b-0f59-4df0-aea9-4a538997f6e6",
            "type" : "apm-server",
            "ephemeral_id" : "d050562a-8d75-4209-b7d0-e81febf38d3d",
            "version" : "7.13.0",
            "version_major" : 7
          },
          "trace" : {
            "id" : "01c92d329ccd92478b83a238e3c01b4a"
          },
          "@timestamp" : "2021-07-19T18:07:31.953Z",
          "ecs" : {
            "version" : "1.8.0"
          },
          "service" : {
            "node" : {
              "name" : "CPX-GLE2FOXH0T3"
            },
            "environment" : "production",
            "framework" : {
              "name" : "ASP.NET Core",
              "version" : "5.0.0.0"
            },
            "name" : "AppTest",
            "runtime" : {
              "name" : ".NET 5",
              "version" : "5.0.5"
            },
            "language" : {
              "name" : "C#"
            },
            "version" : "1.0.0"
          },
          "host" : {
            "hostname" : "CPX-GLE2FOXH0T3",
            "ip" : "172.25.0.1",
            "name" : "CPX-GLE2FOXH0T3"
          },
          "client" : {
            "ip" : "::1"
          },
          "http" : {
            "request" : {
              "headers" : {
                "Cookie" : [
                  ".AspNetCore.Antiforgery.2p9HK2lhxuY=CfDJ8Dx5pi93XlpAlBM6ht9NsLqRNgukbGGnh78TPr3xX0Z_y_FJlWrdLtle0U6p_8j675OuNHXMLqXvnbxdoBN7kcCl4XJrbJxXghxxnOD0cG36SGXjN544e9evy3i9_B1gQHMkqcTTSXkRZ1nSbHF5IzQ,.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.xEn_h8jTrzk=CfDJ8Dx5pi93XlpAlBM6ht9NsLpqaVgX_9OZKpxiQrooy-T3QRS3IJYkpHcsZ1bjWDNbaMNKRoVgAM_42kZLLojP3w9roVqV9CeOmrfH4W2SLXMZzvDHrpOLfgAGABkeTmIJp5BkuBMhCHg7zKgerE72zT8,.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.pWK10f4-nSU=CfDJ8Dx5pi93XlpAlBM6ht9NsLqE4evscYCvbn8gHWTG2rGBL4PZp77mBFUM0oHV8i3kJoamaj2sYos_ImQ6zFy_fDH-RQj02BT4ZQZAibdknXhEzidBJLmdqI3ZppITONjVz_ZVVjKkMTfnHRramkabzhk,.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.tphuApw-2rM=CfDJ8OKn5Y98jFhFj5OjgFbFoJXDU5pnA7XDUkNggYzhtLK3dCxde5OXjIUuU4zDm_6cJ9b3JK6A0k1i9APKs69jGU8_JmoAqDSi3cgnbLEV7xVEThEhMCdaHifsIXyw7rYZMdVBS5403oZfEUOKvpgviM0,.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.ohccJll1qP4=CfDJ8OKn5Y98jFhFj5OjgFbFoJWjauoWueKtAM1D9QkX575_VDMquYoyTciU3uUxyvwr6EW1fFKtdRjgtQoJUy1QthYYbrwNdJBggB7UfOKRpRgim4cOIL34WJ-0i7ayWW7_fliuPcJyo11XnMaiiUa-f3s,.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.u6V5pe-jSMU=CfDJ8OKn5Y98jFhFj5OjgFbFoJVYEagWGJ9Dfp0_g5dY-WMRwCLIzYQzCswRVRR79ELtrEMZQ58Qls-sMebGfgqUlRo-do0_Tu2kFnEL01_9l6Hv2eFSqx2i29ZDTFBSimXSIeKp6WOKJyvHmxp2S1270Uw,.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.nLROWordfdI=CfDJ8OKn5Y98jFhFj5OjgFbFoJUuL5nrnLNA0QoYDQAWAKeFtnvyETdbNan-EGYuOzwJUkD3qwSxXUa-wHnQ94JWUVfztTs-4tZXbGgjsQ0sYZ6M866kvAj1gLfp1-_BpkIk6JyXytRhb0C7w_eddqlxaZA"
                ],
                "Sec-Ch-Ua" : [
                  "\" Not;A Brand\";v=\"99\", \"Google Chrome\";v=\"91\", \"Chromium\";v=\"91\""
                ],
                "Accept" : [
                  "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9"
                ],
                "User-Agent" : [
                  "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36"
                ],
                "Sec-Fetch-Dest" : [
                  "document"
                ],
                "Sec-Fetch-Site" : [
                  "none"
                ],
                "Host" : [
                  "localhost:5001"
                ],
                "Accept-Encoding" : [
                  "gzip, deflate, br"
                ],
                "Sec-Fetch-Mode" : [
                  "navigate"
                ],
                ":method" : [
                  "GET"
                ],
                "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests" : [
                  "1"
                ],
                ":scheme" : [
                  "https"
                ],
                ":path" : [
                  "/"
                ],
                "Sec-Fetch-User" : [
                  "?1"
                ],
                "Accept-Language" : [
                  "en-US,en;q=0.9"
                ],
                "Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile" : [
                  "?0"
                ],
                ":authority" : [
                  "localhost:5001"
                ]
              },
              "method" : "GET",
              "socket" : {
                "encrypted" : true,
                "remote_address" : "::1"
              },
              "body" : {
                "original" : "[REDACTED]"
              }
            },
            "response" : {
              "headers" : {
                "Server" : [
                  "Kestrel"
                ],
                "Date" : [
                  "Mon, 19 Jul 2021 18:07:31 GMT"
                ],
                "Content-Type" : [
                  "text/html; charset=utf-8"
                ]
              },
              "status_code" : 200,
              "finished" : true
            },
            "version" : "2"
          },
          "event" : {
            "ingested" : "2021-07-19T18:07:38.337682900Z",
            "outcome" : "success"
          },
          "transaction" : {
            "result" : "HTTP 2xx",
            "duration" : {
              "us" : 663305
            },
            "name" : "GET Home/Index",
            "span_count" : {
              "dropped" : 0,
              "started" : 0
            },
            "id" : "0bd2bd7f8b94944e",
            "type" : "request",
            "sampled" : true
          },
          "user_agent" : {
            "original" : "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36",
            "os" : {
              "name" : "Windows",
              "version" : "10",
              "full" : "Windows 10"
            },
            "name" : "Chrome",
            "device" : {
              "name" : "Other"
            },
            "version" : "91.0.4472.124"
          },
          "timestamp" : {
            "us" : 1626718051953315
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "apm-7.13.0-transaction-000002",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "3SXzv3oB2DAWJifJt8jM",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "agent" : {
            "name" : "dotnet",
            "version" : "1.11.0+a4eb5008af64ca52fe6973c18810c0c8c7a99554"
          },
          "source" : {
            "ip" : "::1"
          },
          "processor" : {
            "name" : "transaction",
            "event" : "transaction"
          },
          "url" : {
            "path" : "/Second/SecIndex",
            "original" : "https://localhost:5001/Second/SecIndex",
            "scheme" : "HTTP",
            "domain" : "localhost",
            "full" : "https://localhost:5001/Second/SecIndex"
          },
          "observer" : {
            "hostname" : "ef75b7ae7c69",
            "id" : "de63825b-0f59-4df0-aea9-4a538997f6e6",
            "ephemeral_id" : "d050562a-8d75-4209-b7d0-e81febf38d3d",
            "type" : "apm-server",
            "version" : "7.13.0",
            "version_major" : 7
          },
          "trace" : {
            "id" : "92c232e28fe661468065148b329eeed3"
          },
          "@timestamp" : "2021-07-19T18:07:35.443Z",
          "ecs" : {
            "version" : "1.8.0"
          },
          "service" : {
            "node" : {
              "name" : "CPX-GLE2FOXH0T3"
            },
            "environment" : "production",
            "framework" : {
              "name" : "ASP.NET Core",
              "version" : "5.0.0.0"
            },
            "name" : "AppTest",
            "runtime" : {
              "name" : ".NET 5",
              "version" : "5.0.5"
            },
            "language" : {
              "name" : "C#"
            },
            "version" : "1.0.0"
          },
          "host" : {
            "hostname" : "CPX-GLE2FOXH0T3",
            "ip" : "172.25.0.1",
            "name" : "CPX-GLE2FOXH0T3"
          },
          "http" : {
            "request" : {
              "headers" : {
                "Cookie" : [
                  ".AspNetCore.Antiforgery.2p9HK2lhxuY=CfDJ8Dx5pi93XlpAlBM6ht9NsLqRNgukbGGnh78TPr3xX0Z_y_FJlWrdLtle0U6p_8j675OuNHXMLqXvnbxdoBN7kcCl4XJrbJxXghxxnOD0cG36SGXjN544e9evy3i9_B1gQHMkqcTTSXkRZ1nSbHF5IzQ,.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.xEn_h8jTrzk=CfDJ8Dx5pi93XlpAlBM6ht9NsLpqaVgX_9OZKpxiQrooy-T3QRS3IJYkpHcsZ1bjWDNbaMNKRoVgAM_42kZLLojP3w9roVqV9CeOmrfH4W2SLXMZzvDHrpOLfgAGABkeTmIJp5BkuBMhCHg7zKgerE72zT8,.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.pWK10f4-nSU=CfDJ8Dx5pi93XlpAlBM6ht9NsLqE4evscYCvbn8gHWTG2rGBL4PZp77mBFUM0oHV8i3kJoamaj2sYos_ImQ6zFy_fDH-RQj02BT4ZQZAibdknXhEzidBJLmdqI3ZppITONjVz_ZVVjKkMTfnHRramkabzhk,.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.tphuApw-2rM=CfDJ8OKn5Y98jFhFj5OjgFbFoJXDU5pnA7XDUkNggYzhtLK3dCxde5OXjIUuU4zDm_6cJ9b3JK6A0k1i9APKs69jGU8_JmoAqDSi3cgnbLEV7xVEThEhMCdaHifsIXyw7rYZMdVBS5403oZfEUOKvpgviM0,.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.ohccJll1qP4=CfDJ8OKn5Y98jFhFj5OjgFbFoJWjauoWueKtAM1D9QkX575_VDMquYoyTciU3uUxyvwr6EW1fFKtdRjgtQoJUy1QthYYbrwNdJBggB7UfOKRpRgim4cOIL34WJ-0i7ayWW7_fliuPcJyo11XnMaiiUa-f3s,.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.u6V5pe-jSMU=CfDJ8OKn5Y98jFhFj5OjgFbFoJVYEagWGJ9Dfp0_g5dY-WMRwCLIzYQzCswRVRR79ELtrEMZQ58Qls-sMebGfgqUlRo-do0_Tu2kFnEL01_9l6Hv2eFSqx2i29ZDTFBSimXSIeKp6WOKJyvHmxp2S1270Uw,.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.nLROWordfdI=CfDJ8OKn5Y98jFhFj5OjgFbFoJUuL5nrnLNA0QoYDQAWAKeFtnvyETdbNan-EGYuOzwJUkD3qwSxXUa-wHnQ94JWUVfztTs-4tZXbGgjsQ0sYZ6M866kvAj1gLfp1-_BpkIk6JyXytRhb0C7w_eddqlxaZA"
                ],
                "Sec-Ch-Ua" : [
                  "\" Not;A Brand\";v=\"99\", \"Google Chrome\";v=\"91\", \"Chromium\";v=\"91\""
                ],
                "Accept" : [
                  "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9"
                ],
                "User-Agent" : [
                  "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36"
                ],
                "Referer" : [
                  "https://localhost:5001/"
                ],
                "Sec-Fetch-Site" : [
                  "same-origin"
                ],
                "Sec-Fetch-Dest" : [
                  "document"
                ],
                "Host" : [
                  "localhost:5001"
                ],
                "Accept-Encoding" : [
                  "gzip, deflate, br"
                ],
                "Sec-Fetch-Mode" : [
                  "navigate"
                ],
                ":method" : [
                  "GET"
                ],
                "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests" : [
                  "1"
                ],
                ":scheme" : [
                  "https"
                ],
                ":path" : [
                  "/Second/SecIndex"
                ],
                "Sec-Fetch-User" : [
                  "?1"
                ],
                "Accept-Language" : [
                  "en-US,en;q=0.9"
                ],
                "Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile" : [
                  "?0"
                ],
                ":authority" : [
                  "localhost:5001"
                ]
              },
              "method" : "GET",
              "socket" : {
                "encrypted" : true,
                "remote_address" : "::1"
              },
              "body" : {
                "original" : "[REDACTED]"
              }
            },
            "response" : {
              "headers" : {
                "Cache-Control" : [
                  "no-cache, no-store"
                ],
                "Server" : [
                  "Kestrel"
                ],
                "Pragma" : [
                  "no-cache"
                ],
                "Date" : [
                  "Mon, 19 Jul 2021 18:07:34 GMT"
                ],
                "Content-Type" : [
                  "text/html; charset=utf-8"
                ]
              },
              "status_code" : 200,
              "finished" : true
            },
            "version" : "2"
          },
          "client" : {
            "ip" : "::1"
          },
          "event" : {
            "ingested" : "2021-07-19T18:07:38.439690700Z",
            "outcome" : "success"
          },
          "transaction" : {
            "duration" : {
              "us" : 64185
            },
            "result" : "HTTP 2xx",
            "name" : "GET Second/SecIndex",
            "span_count" : {
              "dropped" : 0,
              "started" : 0
            },
            "id" : "bc217d42a1806b40",
            "type" : "request",
            "sampled" : true
          },
          "user_agent" : {
            "original" : "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36",
            "os" : {
              "name" : "Windows",
              "version" : "10",
              "full" : "Windows 10"
            },
            "name" : "Chrome",
            "device" : {
              "name" : "Other"
            },
            "version" : "91.0.4472.124"
          },
          "timestamp" : {
            "us" : 1626718055443632
          }
        }
      },
```

However, what I cannot seem to determine is if there is a unique ID that will act as the parent ID /session ID that can correlate all the logs in a single activity. At first, I noticed that inside of the `observer{}` scope, there was an `id` and a `ephemeral_id` and when I searched for either of those id's from the result that the query dsl cmd gave me, it returned a total of 5 hits (for all of the 5 transactions made). But when I ran the query dsl cmd again but with a different timestamp I still had the same `id` and `ephemeral_id` so I knew that was not the ID that uniquely identifies the logs per a single activity. **Is there a unique ID that uniquely identifies from the start to finish of an activity?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Transactions](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/get-started/current/transactions.html) can be considered the *root* span for a trace, where a sampled transaction might have a collection of [spans](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/get-started/current/transaction-spans.html) associated with it. These associated spans are stored in separate indices with the index pattern `apm-*-span` where the `_source.transaction.id` is the id of the parent transaction.

[A distributed trace](https://www.w3.org/TR/trace-context/#dfn-distributed-traces) can span multiple services and hence multiple transactions.  Transactions in a distributed trace will share a unique `_source.trace.id` which uniquely identifies the distributed trace through a system.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation!